# How to sort a list of objects using an Angular 2 Pipe

Tags: typescript, angular

I am trying to create a pipe that will sort an array of a custom type.

```
// custom-object.ts
export class CustomObject {
    constructor(
        public someString: string,
        public someNumber: number
    ) {}
}
```

In my html is:

```
// custom-object-form.component.ts
<div class="form-group">
    <label for="cricos_course_code">Object: </label>
    <select class="form-control" required [(ngModel)]="model.someString">
        <option *ngFor="#object of (customObjects | sortArrayOfCustomObjects)" [value]="object.someString">{{object.someString}}</option>
    </select>
</div>
```

Then the code for the pipe:

```
// sort-custom-object.pipe.ts
import {Pipe, PipeTransform} from 'angular2/core';
import {CustomObject} from '../custom-object';

@Pipe({name: 'sortArrayOfCustomObjects'})
export class SortArrayOfCustomObjectsPipe implements PipeTransform {
  transform(arr:Array<CustomObject>): any {
    return arr.sort((a, b) => {
      if (a.someString > b.someString) {
        return 1;
      }
      if (a.someString < b.someString) {
        return -1;
      }
      // a must be equal to b
      return 0;
    });
  }
}
```

Now I am getting an error in the console:

```
EXCEPTION: TypeError: Cannot read property 'sort' of undefined in [(customObjects | sortArrayOfCustomObjects) in FormComponent@7:24]
```

Comment: Are you looking for `args: Array<string | number>`?

Comment: More along the lines of args: Array<CustomObject.someString | CustomObject.someNumber>. Then in my sort function (which doesn't seem to work?) I can change the sorting based on the supplied arguements.

Comment: The issue with `Array<CustomObject.someString | CustomObject.someNumber>` is that those are *properties* not *types*. The *type* of `CustomObject.someString` is a `string`. Therefor you cannot use `CustomObject.someString` as a *type*. Can you provide more information about your needs?

Comment: I have an array of objects that contain properties `p1: string, p2: number `etc. In my form I want to have 2 select fields that show a list of p1 in alphabetical order and p2 in descending order. I thought I could use a pipe like `*ngFor="item of items | sortItems"`.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Based off of your limited information I believe you want the following.

```
@Pipe({name: 'sortArrayOfCustomObjects'})
export class SortArrayOfCustomObjectsPipe implements PipeTransform {

  transform(arr: CustomObject[], args: any): CustomObject[]{
    return arr.sort((a, b) => {
      if (a.p1 > b.p1 || a.p2 < b.p2) {
        return 1;
      }
      if (a.p1 < b.p1 || a.p2 > b.p2) {
        return -1;
      }
      return 0;
    });
  }
}
```

This will sort the objects first by p1, and then by p2. For instance.

```
{p1: 'AA', p2: 3},
{p1: 'CC', p2: 2},
{p1: 'BB', p2: 5},
{p1: 'BB', p2: 1},
{p1: 'AA', p2: 2},
{p1: 'DD', p2: 4}
```

Would be sorted to

```
{p1: 'AA', p2: 3},
{p1: 'AA', p2: 2},
{p1: 'BB', p2: 5},
{p1: 'BB', p2: 1},
{p1: 'CC', p2: 2},
{p1: 'DD', p2: 4}
```

This is based on your comment:

> I have an array of objects that contain properties p1: string, p2: number etc. In my form I want to have 2 select fields that show a list of p1 in alphabetical order and p2 in descending order.

Usage would be

```
*ngFor="#item of (items | sortArrayOfCustomObjects)"
```

**UPDATE**

For your error that you are now receiving be sure to guard against `undefined` values in arrays by using a guard.

```
transform(arr: CustomObject[], args: any): CustomObject[]{
  if(!arr){ return; }
  ...
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I am getting a TypeError: arr is undefined...? What would be causing this? The code works if I just return arr in my transform method though.

Comment: Updated answer to include parenthesis around usage (found in angular docs [here](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/pipes.html) way down close to the bottom).

Comment: I tried the parenthesis, but the error is still showing up. I have updated the question to try and provide some more detail as well.

Comment: Can you post the relevant parts of your component code, where you are assigning the value of `customObjects` is it possible that you are not assigning it a value? or perhaps an async issue. You could guard against this with an `if` statement in the `transform` function that checks if `arr` is `undefined` and if so returns either an empty array or `undefined` before it reaches the `arr.sort(...)` line.

Comment: Ah that was it! `if (arr === undefined) { return arr; } else { ... }` works. Would it be best practice to use the stateful AsyncPipe mentioned here? https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/pipes.html

Comment: Only if your data is in a `Promise` or `Observable`. Otherwise using that will cause errors as well.